# Access-Control-Allow-Origin in wordpress php on nginx server

Tags: php, wordpress

I am not able to allow Access-Control-Allow-Origin in wordpress on nginx server i have done like allow **`Access-Control-Allow-Origin :*`** but it not working how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding these as using * is not secure.

```
add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' "$http_origin";
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'User-Agent,Keep-Alive,Content-Type';
```

Comment: where i have to add in my wordpress php  file?

Comment: you have to add it in nginx conf file.